# Turning a string into an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am trying to create an object out of string which is not a typical JSON string.

Here is the example:

```js
 var ObjectInString = "{x:62.43993,y:293.64093}"; //string i want to turn into an object
var ObjectWhichWorks = {x:62.43993,y:293.64093};

console.log(ObjectInString);
console.log(ObjectWhichWorks);
```

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(string)` to convert string to object

Comment: Are you having the [same problem as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval)? If so, this is a duplicate. If not, please explain why.

Comment: Solution to this question does not work for me.

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ObjectInString))`

Comment: I need to have the same output as is given on object in snipped.

Comment: @AESTHETICS—you say that the answers to [*Parsing “relaxed” JSON without eval*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval) do not work for you, yet your accepted answer is the same as the highest voted answer there and your question seems identical.

Comment: I did not expect it to be done this way as my object did not look like an JSON object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing "relaxed" JSON without eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517/parsing-relaxed-json-without-eval)

Comment: Can you guys leave this post? It has accepted solution which is clear and not multiple answers which are hard to get through and understand the meaning of it.

Comment: @AESTHETICS—that's not how it works. You post, other respond. Answers are for everyone, not just you. There's no point in duplicate questions with duplicate answers. The voting systems allows higher voted answers to be ranked over lower ones, so if you find an answer that suits, vote for it.

Comment: I understand but other posts that got linked are not perfect as one has multiple answers, no accepted answer and the other has the title which is really hard to find/search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your keys are always `x` and `y`, convert the string to a valid JSON string by adding double quotes around those keys.  You can then use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get the desired object:

```js
var o = '{x:62.43993,y:293.64093}';

console.log(JSON.parse(o.replace('x', '"x"').replace('y', '"y"')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` to interpret a JavaScript expression inside of a string. We need to wrap this value in parentheses for it to be parsed properly as an object literal, instead of an invalid statement.

```js
var ObjectInString = "{x:62.43993,y:293.64093}";
var Object = eval("(" + ObjectInString + ")");

console.log(ObjectInString);
console.log(Object);
```

However, **using `eval` with untrusted data is a massive security vulnerability**. Only do this with data from sources that are entirely trusted, and look for alternatives (such as using valid JSON data you can parse with `JSON.parse(...)` as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

many years ago i search alot for this solution.

```
var obj = eval ("(" + ObjectInString + ")");
```

i don't know about cross browser support or anything else, just know it work for me.